# excerpt length in Child Theme

Tags: php, wordpress

Once again my amature php skills have me pinned down by its strings!

I am trying to change the excerpt length of the post summaries on my Wordpress blog page. So far I have created a child theme, replaces the content.php file code to

```
<div class="entry-content">
            <?php the_excerpt( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyeleven' ) ); ?>
            <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link"><span>' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyeleven' ) . '</span>', 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-content -->
```

and added a functions file with the following code

```
    <?php

function CHILDTHEME_excerpt_length($length) {
    return 600;
}
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'CHILDTHEME_excerpt_length'); ?>
```

AND what do you know...... It still remains the same length of summary on the blog page as before. What am I doing wrong?

All help is very much appreciated as always

Answer (score 1):

You must set the filter priority right:

```
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'CHILDTHEME_excerpt_length', 999);
```

Without specifying the priority WordPress filter on this function will run last and override what you set here.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a filter that is running after yours and resetting the length. You can set a higher priority, this can be guesswork until you get it high enough. Another option is to remove all the existing filters for this hook before you add yours:

```
function my_excerpt_length($length){
   return 400;
}
remove_all_filters( 'excerpt_length' );
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'my_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

Comment: This is still not working, do I need to do something to the content.php file code?

Comment: Oops, try adding the 999 priority to the filter. You shouldn't need to change `content.php` as it is using `the_excerpt()` which will process the filters.

Comment: <?php
remove_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'twentyeleven_excerpt_length' );
 
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'new_excerpt_length', 999);
function new_excerpt_length($length) {
  return 1020;
}

?>

Comment: And <?php
remove_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'twentyeleven_excerpt_length' );
 
add_filter(999, 'excerpt_length', 'new_excerpt_length');
function new_excerpt_length($length) {
  return 1020;
}

?> STILL DO NOT WORK - PLEASE HELP ARGHHHHHHHHH

Comment: For debugging: search code to see if there are other instances of `excerpt_length`, set the priority higher on your filter `9999`, add an `error_log()` line to your filter to make sure it is running, hook all of the code (`remove_filter` and `add_filter`) into an action that runs later, like `init` maybe.